# React: how to delete some elements and get rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React, so I cant understand what is wrong. When I delete some elements, they are no deleted because `getData()` is called quicker than `setRecipes(updatedRecipes)`. So in `getData()` the array is incorrect and set old, so nothing changed.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { create } from 'zustand';
import RecipesList from "../components/RecipesList";

const useRecipesStore = create((set) => ({
    recipes: [],
    curPosition: 0,
    setRecipes: (data) => set((state) => ({ recipes: data })),
    setCurPosition: (curPosition) => set((state) => ({ curPosition })),
}));

const Home = () => {
    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);
    const recipes = useRecipesStore((state) => state.recipes);
    const setRecipes = useRecipesStore((state) => state.setRecipes);
    const recipesPerPage = 15;
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
    const curPosition = useRecipesStore((state) => state.curPosition);
    const setCurPosition = useRecipesStore((state) => state.setCurPosition);

    const url = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${pageNumber}&per_page=${recipesPerPage}`;

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(url);
          if(pageNumber === 1){
            setRecipes(data);
          } else {
            const limit = recipesPerPage - recipes.length
            const arr = [...recipes, ...data.slice(curPosition, curPosition + limit)];
            console.log("data ", recipes)
            console.log("slice ", data.slice(curPosition, curPosition + limit))
            console.log("curPosition ", curPosition)
            console.log("limit ", limit)
            setRecipes(arr);
            setCurPosition(curPosition + limit) 
          }  
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);
  
    const handleSelectionChange = (selectedIds) => {
        setSelectedItems(selectedIds);
    };

    const handleDelete = () => {
        if(curPosition === 0){
            setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber+1);
        } 
        const updatedRecipes = recipes.filter((recipe) => !selectedItems.map(Number).includes(recipe.id));
        setSelectedItems([]);
        setRecipes(updatedRecipes);
        console.log("updatedRecipes ", updatedRecipes)
        getData()
    };

    return (<>
        {selectedItems.length > 0 && 
            (<button onClick={handleDelete} className="delete-button">
                Delete
            </button>)
        }
        
        <RecipesList recipes={recipes} onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}/>
    </>);
}

export default Home;
```

I changed a little and had another problem. Pagenumber is not updated although I used setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);

````
const updateArray = async(updatedRecipes) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url);
        if(curPosition === 0){
            setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
            console.log(pageNumber)
        } 
        const limit = recipesPerPage - updatedRecipes.length
        const arr = [...updatedRecipes, ...data.slice(curPosition, curPosition + limit)];

        console.log("data ", updatedRecipes)
        console.log("slice ", data.slice(curPosition, curPosition + limit))
        console.log("curPosition ", curPosition)
        console.log("limit ", limit)

        setRecipes(arr);
        if(curPosition + limit >= recipesPerPage){
            setCurPosition(0)
        } else {
            setCurPosition(curPosition + limit) 
        }
    }```
````

Comment: If I didnt call getData in handleDelete, so getData wouldnt be called

Comment: @VictorL. I cant join

Comment: no, and I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there

Comment: You must know that update states functions are async and the pageNumber you're printing is the old value, you will see the new value in the next render. What you can do is create a new variable `const newPageNumber = pageNumber + 1` set that value and use it for any other thing you want to do in your function

Comment: I make request for getting data. So because of value of page number is not updated, I get old value @bbernag

Comment: Maybe you are available now. please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254513/chatting-with-victor

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that you always update the latest value of setState you have to use it like:

```
setPageNumber(actualValue => actualValue + 1);
```

where `actualValue` is the latest value here.

If you use it this way `setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);`, in meantime `pageNumber` can be changed async and you can have old value in there.

Reference [link](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate)